# past progressive with dependent clause -- dependent clause types in the face of ambiguity

Tags: grammar, terminology, dependent-clause, adverbials

I'm trying to explain how to contrast the following two sentences in a meaningful - detailed - way.

> I was eating when a bee stung me.
>
> I was eating when I was on a break.

The intention is to teach ESL learners to understand that the first as an "interruption" statement but the second is not.
I'd like to avoid saying "you just have to understand the context".
I feel like the function is different enough that maybe, maybe we can.

Is there a way to define a difference in those two
"when" clauses
to predict the function
based on the grammar of the clause or words?

Comment: Did this stuff come up in a lesson in a textbook?

Comment: The second is durative stative, so _while_ can be used, while the first is punctual active, so _while_ won't work. The punctual "interruption" sense of _when_ can be replaced by _and,_ because simple time order provides the same effect.

Comment: I would spend some attention on the word **on** in "on a break".  On the phone, on holiday, on a break, on and on.

Comment: @michael_timofeev -- nope :)   just in class

Comment: @JohnLawler-  I appreciate those details.   Rewriting with "while" certainly makes sense to prevent the question....  I'm really curious if there's any way to answer it as it is...  ( I won't be surprised if there is or there isn't )

Comment: @JohnLawler --  and thank you for the terminology...  that is definitely part of what I need to learn

Comment: What level are the students in terms of listening ability and grammar understanding?

Comment: @JohnLawler so in sentences, if the event is viewed in a durative sense, "when" can be used but in a conjunction sense?  How does one teach this?  It seems to be something that is built-in in terms of an English speaker's way of viewing events.  As a teacher is there a linguistic test I could quickly apply to a sentence to see how it is viewed in time?

Comment: @michael: No. That may be true, but that's not what I said. I said **in this sentence** that's the way it falls out. No guarantee for other situations. There are many ways to view things in time; in this case there is an ongoing activity (_eating_) and either a punctual or a durative activity introduced by _when_, indicating simultaneity.  But a punctual event can't be simultaneous with a duration; it happens at a point in time. So in order for it to have _when_ it would have to be an interruption (unless you were eating bees). _While_ can be used with two duratives.

Comment: @michael_timofeev -- very mixed low level --  think CEFR A1,2 ----  Obviously, only some exceptional students - the two that talked to me about this --  are going to benefit directly from parsing this out.

Comment: @MikeM ok.  I've found that keeping grammar discussions in line with listening abilities is important.  It is often surprising to me how little the students understand, regardless of how slow one speaks or the amount of downgrading.  That said, I don't dumb things down.  I guess I choose my confusion opportunities wisely.  Btw, I've faced this topic before...I know what a can of worms it opens.

Comment: @michael_timofeev -- yup, this is an after-class type thing....  I want to encourage these students that are actually willing and able to have this discussion

Comment: @michael_timofeev -- so I guess I should have answered your first question more carefully...    If I can get a detailed answer to this question, it is not really about the level.  So don't worry too much about that.
That will be something to think about after.

Comment: @MikeM btw, if you don't have a copy, I suggest you purchase The Teacher's Grammar of English by Ron Cowan.  Excellent book...well worth any money to get it.

Comment: @michael_timofeev --  thank you for the recommendation!

Comment: @John Lawler -  I tried reading more online about durative and stative aspect.   The first hit on Google is this stackexchange page... so it's not such a popular topic.  Do you know somewhere I could read more about these ideas?

Answer (score 2):

[1] *I was eating, when a bee stung me.*

[2] *I was eating when I was on a break.*

The *when* phrases are both adjuncts, but the difference is that in [1] the phrase is a supplement, and in [2] it’s a modifier.

In [2] we have a phrase that is tightly integrated into the structure of the clause, an indispensable part of it. It’s restrictive in that it denotes precisely when I was eating: I was not eating at some random time, but specifically when I was on a break.

By contrast, in [1] we have a non-integrated loosely attached phrase giving some useful but non-essential information. It doesn’t define when you were eating; rather it says that you were eating, and while you were, you happened to be stung by a bee. Loose adjuncts of this kind are called supplements. I’d recommend inserting a comma as shown to mark it as a supplement as opposed to a modifier. In speech, it would typically be marked off by what is perceived as a slight pause. By virtue of being non-integrated, it is semantically non-restrictive.

Comment: Thanks for all these details.  I'm definitely trying to learn this terminology here.

What you've done though is unexpectedly add the corollary of whether or not we can add a comma in #1 :-)

My informal opinion thinks that using the comma is the answer to separating the two cases.
But I didn't put it in my question because several people I've talked to in person say it isn't allowed.

Can you point me to some other references that talk about using that comma?

Comment: @MikeM the problem you are still going to run into is the valid student question about the use of the word "when."  It's all fine and dandy to discuss the clauses and commas but the students are going to come from a practical standpoint and ask for a rule of some sort, or you will find that they start using "when" in ways not acceptable.  I haven't had to teach this in a while but when I last did there were all sorts of valid questions about when while and during.

Comment: @michael_timofeev -- absolutely.  But first things first   ---  can we find a rule for reading these sentences that doesn't quite depend on "just knowing".   Clearly since any answer - if there is one - will be pretty exotic, it will only be useful for the 2 students that are advanced enough to have asked it.   But I promised to find one, so here we are :-)

Comment: @MikeM yes, I would love to have a generally applicable observation.  Professor Lawler's answer gave me some food for thought.  I'm hoping some others will comment on this question.  Personally, I hate telling students something is idiomatic or you just have to be exposed enough...I prefer to give guidelines and ideas to help them see that English isn't so random and that they can speak it.

Comment: @MikeM I don't think there's any doubt that in speech the supplement would be set off by a slight pause, so there's no reason why you can't mark it in writing as a supp by popping in a comma. Most supps are set off that way. Although both when clauses are adjuncts, optional elements rather than obligatory, a pause/comma are still the best indicators here.

Comment: @BillJ -  I definitely get your point.  And I would say I agree it makes sense and would be very useful to use the comma this way.  Do you know of any reference material we can cite to share with other professionals?